# Substract first sentence of the text and echo it, then echo the remaining text

Tags: php

```
$content = 'this is a small text';
$content = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($content, 0, 100)); // i substract the first 100 chars from the text - only whole words
echo $content;
```

Is there a way to substract the first sentence in the text and echo it? Lets say untill the text reachers a "." or a "?" or a "!" ?

And then echo the remaining part of the text?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern something like  (.*?[?.!]) will match the first sentence.

```
$content = "First sentence. Then. Many. More.";
preg_match('/(.*?[?.!])(.*)/', $content, $match);

$first_sentence = $match[1];
$the_rest = $match[2];
```

But this will work.

```
 $content = "First sentence? Then. Many. More.";
```

Comment: This works great, what if the first sentance ends in "..." Or, the text is really small and lets say i have this: "this is the only sentente in the text and i'm not finished with any punctuation" Thank you

Comment: You ask only for . ? ! not for ellipsis '/(.*?([?.!]|[.]{3}))(.*)/' will work with ellipsis. $match[2] contains the pontuaction symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You could use strtok instead.

```
$content = 'This is a small text. With a second Sentance.';
$first = strtok($content, '.?!');
$rest = substr($content, 0, strlen($first));
```

This is easier to ad tokens to.

Comment: Waht if i want to add "..." suspension points i think they are called?

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "First sentence. Then. Many. More.";
preg_match('/^([^.]+)\.\s*(.*)$/', $content, $match);

$first_sentence = $match[1];
$the_rest = $match[2];
```

The first group `([^.]+)` matches one or more characters not being a dot `.`

Then it expects a dot followed by zero or more whitespace `\.\s*`

Then the rest until the end of `$content`: `(.*)$`